# Problems to login in Ubuntu 14.04 after new update (Friday)

Tags: 14.04, login-screen

Yesterday (November 4), I update my Ubuntu 14.04. After that I can't login. It something like a loop. I type the password, enter and it's return to login-screen.

The same happen if try the guest mode.

After some research, I found that the problems isn't with the login itself. But with the video card driver.

Any clue?

Comment: Do you have a Nvidia card and proprietary drivers installed?

Comment: Yes. I have Nvidia card. And I have proprietary drivers installed. I am not sure if what driver of Nvidia I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I cannot comment your question (not enough reputation point) and this is not a complete answer.

I have the exact same problem. It seems related to nvidia driver update (when reinstalling nvidia-driver you can see an error for not finding `systemctl` that might explain the issue).

I uninstalled all nvidia package with:

```
sudo apt-get remove -purge nvidia*
```

It allows me to login again, but of course I do use only the Intel graphic driver.

Any solution to get back the ability to switch between Intel and Nvidia would be welcome ;-)

Comment: You are assuming the OP has a Nvidia card installed.